Show the difference between two matrices is positive definite
We have $NT$ i.i.d. observations $\left(X_{it},Y_{it}\right)_{it}$. Assume
the regression model ${Y}={X}{\beta}+{e}$, where ${Y}$ and ${e}$
are $NT\times1$ vectors, and ${X}$ is an $NT\times K$ matrix.
We can rewrite the model as ${Y}_{i}={X}_{i}{\beta}+{e}_{i}$,
where for each $i=1,2,\ldots,N$, ${Y}_{i}$ and ${e}_{i}$
are $T\times1$ vectors, and ${X}_{i}$ is a $T\times K$ matrix.
Hence, the residual can be obtain as $\hat{{e}}_{i}={Y}_{i}-{X}_{i}\hat{{\beta}}$,
where $\hat{{\beta}}=\left({X}^{\top}{X}\right)^{-1}{X}^{\top}{Y}$.
The annihilation matrix ${M}={I}-{X}\left({X}^{\top}{X}\right)^{-1}{X}^{\top}$
is an $NT\times NT$ matrix. Define ${M}_{ii}$ to be the $i^{th}$
diagonal block matrix of ${M}$, and hence ${M}_{ii}$ is a
$T\times T$ matrix.
Let $\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert $ be the spectral norm (the largest
singular value). We have some properties that may be useful for ${M}_{ii}$:

${M}_{ii}$ is symmetric;
$0\leq\left\Vert {M}_{ii}\right\Vert \leq1$;
$\left\Vert {M}_{ii}^{-1}\right\Vert \geq\left\Vert {M}_{ii}\right\Vert ^{-1}=1$.

Then, are we able to show th at $P\left({M}_{ii}^{-1}\hat{{e}}_{i}\hat{{e}}_{i}^{\top}{M}_{ii}^{-1}-\hat{{e}}_{i}\hat{{e}}_{i}^{\top}>0\right)\rightarrow1$,
as $T\rightarrow\infty$, where ${A}>0$ means the matrix ${A}$
is positive definite?
Note that $N$ is fixed here, otherwise if $N\rightarrow \infty$, I believe we need at least $T=N^3$ to have the result holds.
